# How to move the form label into the input field on all node edit forms

Tags: nodes, theming

I have been able to customize it in the search form using template file. I am not able to figure out how to do this in the node creation/edit forms.
eg: http://drupal.org search box at the left top.

Answer (score 1):

I overrode the form in the template.php

```
$form['title']['#attributes'] = array(
  'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = '".$form['title']['#value']."';} this.style.color = '#333333';",
  'onfocus' => "if (this.value == '".$form['title']['#value']."') {this.value = '';} this.style.color = '#333333';" 
);
```